# VS Code Jupyter Notebook Markdown Display Font

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, jupyter

Is there some way to modify the font in which the rendered markdown cell is displayed in VS Code's Jupyter Notebook? I have searched the internet to resolve this matter, but all I understand was that this is done by default as shown in the screenshot provided in [Working with Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support). The screenshot below clearly shows that the font for rendered markdown cell is different than the one set for code cells
[image: Screenshot from official webpage]

On the other hand, My VS Code notebook Looks like this
[image: VS Code Python Notebook on my Installation]
It seems that render font for markdown has somehow been linked with the font for code cells. If I change the font for the code cell, the markdown cell render font changes too.

In settings, I found an option to set fonts for markdown preview, and I changed it to Arial, but this does not have any effect on markdown cell
[image: Font setting for markdown]

I finally decided to completely uninstall VS Code, by uninstalling through control panel, then removing remaining folders from `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code` and `%userprofile%\.vscode`. Afterwards, I reinstall VS Code from the latest available stable installer and reinstalled the required extensions. But the problem still persists.

I would really appreciate any help regarding this matter

Comment: Same problem here with the insider version. Have you posted it to the issue section of vscode on github? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: Or maybe on this subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode

Comment: The new insider build (1.53) has added sans-serif font display in the markdown cells, along with an outline.Unfortunately, the markdown display options are still ignored and many things now are broken, like the support for interactive plotly figures and equations in markdown cells.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the Font Size and other things too...

- * -> Bullet Points
  [image: Bullet Point Image]
- *** -> Creates Border Line
  [image: Border Image]
- # -> Largest font Size
  [image: Large Font Image]
- ## -> Medium Font Size
  [image: Medium Font Image]
- ### -> Smallest Font Size
  [image: Small Font Image]
- ` (Back Ticks) -> Mark the Text with Color
  [image: Back Tick Image]
- > -> Shade the Entire Current Cell
  [image: Shaded Shell Image]

One last thing, to apply these effects you have to press `ctrl + enter`
for every shell

Comment: I am aware of the markdown formatting techniques. And if you look closely at the second screenshot shared, the markdown cell has been rendered using `Ctrl + Enter` and that is the reason that we can see the quote block and the code block. The issue is that the texts other than the `code` is also rendered with mono-spaced font.

Answer (score 2):

I found following temporary solution, and I'm leaving it here for just for another time I'll come back to this question again.

"Add a code cell in the Jupiter Notebook and run it. If you want to roll back to default font - just delete the cell:"

```
%%HTML
<style>
    body {
        --vscode-font-family: "ComicSansMS"
    }
</style>
```

Also it's possible to modify only part of text in markdown cell with

```
<p style="font-family:ComicSansMS; font-size: 48px;"> Insert some text here</p>
```

That example change both font and font size.

Answer (score -1):

This may help: [Incorrect font used in notebook Markdown code blocks](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146696).

> Apply editor-font-family to all code in notebooks (microsoft#157554)
>
> Apply editor-font-family to all `code` in notebook
>
> Fixes [microsoft#146696](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146696)
>
> This matches what we do in the markdown preview

- from https://github.com/Maxxisthename/vscode/commit/0103536a602d5acaffb3f4a39d8c5b31046c272b

So the editor font family you set in the settings (`Editor: Font Family`) should be respected in the markdown of notebook cells.  If that helps...